# Problems with conecting Spring boot 2.7.16 with 7.17 client and Elasticsearch 7.10.2 (AWS)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have Spring boot version 2.7.16 and spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch client to 7.17 (also tried lower versions). I have Amazon Elasticsearch Service version 7.10.2 running at the moment (also tried the OpenSearch AWS engine).

I have made the necessary code changes but I get the below error:

I faced different types of errors from application failing to start and getting crash loop on my k8s pod to:
1)"Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INDEX_CONTENT_TYPE"
2)"Pre-bound JDBC Connection found! JpaTransactionManager does not support running within DataSourceTransactionManager if told to manage the DataSource itself. It is recommended to use a single JpaTransactionManager for all transactions on a single DataSource, no matter whether JPA or JDBC access."
3)"org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Invalid or missing build flavor [oss]"

I could change the version of the elastic library or version ElasticSearch version on AWS but I don't want to upgrade the Spring Boot version. Any ideas on how to handle this? Thanks in Advance!

Tried different combinations of org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch and ElasticSearch engine versions on AWS but no resutls so far

Comment: Error1 seemes like an incompatibility between the Elasticsearch client library and the server. Error 2 has nothing to do with Elasticsearch connections at all. Error 3 comes from the fact that the 7,27 client does not work with the [oss] Elasticsearch variant that AWS uses. All tese used libraries have already EOL. I don't know if AWS offers an Elasticsearch > 7.10 or if you need to switch to Opensearch, but then might need to use spring-data-opensearch